# Using Microsoft.Identity.Web RequiredScope to verify the scopes at the level of the controller - Does not verify scope

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm using the eShopOnContainers sample for .NET microservices architecture and have switched to AD B2C instead of IdentityServer4 for microservice authentication.

Initial set up here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71874003/3850405

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.MetadataAddress = $"<iss URL>.well-known/openid-configuration?p=<tfp>";
    options.Audience = "<aud GUID>";
});
```

This works really well but in the next stage I want to verify that a user has the required scope.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore#verify-the-scopes-at-the-level-of-the-controller

I then added this to my controller:

```
[Authorize]
[RequiredScope("read")]
```

Verified that my access token has scope read using https://jwt.io/

```
"scp": "read",
```

[image]

If I then make a request like this everything works:

```
GET /WeatherForecast HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7148
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

[image]

However if I change `RequiredScope` to `[RequiredScope("abc123")]` and use the same token everything will still work. What needs to be added for `RequiredScope` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was missing was this from Github:

> You can use the `RequiredScopes` attribute when you have used
> `Microsoft.Identity.Web` `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` as it registers
> the scope handler.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/authorization-policies

I then followed this guide for a start:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration#starting-from-an-existing-aspnet-core-31-application

Code in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

})
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration);
```

Values needed in `appsettings.json`:

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://<subdomain>.b2clogin.com/tfp/", //If your domain name is abc123.onmicrosoft.com use abc123 as subdomain. You can find this value on iss in access token or on Azure portal. Use the same subdomain as <subdomain>.onmicrosoft.com
  "ClientId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", //aud or azp in access token. Azure portal App Registration shows it as Application (client) ID
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signupsignin", //User flow used to sign in. tfp in access token
  //Tenant URL
  "Domain": "<subdomain>.onmicrosoft.com" //Get domain name from Azure portal or iss in access token.
},
```

or

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://<subdomain>.b2clogin.com/",
  "ClientId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "TenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", // Can be found in access token on https://<subdomain>.b2clogin.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/v2.0/. Use the guid value. Azure portal has the value as Directory (tenant) ID on a App registration
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signupsignin",
  //Tenant URL
  "Domain": "<subdomain>.onmicrosoft.com"
},
```

Using the wrong scope I received http status 403 Forbidden as expected.

[image]